# Setting up a blog theme to github pages

Tags: github, github-pages, github-for-windows

I am trying to setup a blog on github pages. So i liked this [theme](https://github.com/niklasbuschmann/contrast)  I have read some where that if you fork the theme then you set it to gh-pages and change the repo's name then github will live theme for you. I did exactly the same but there is some problem with the outcome it doesn't look exactly what it is in the theme. Here is [link](https://zeeshanshabbir.github.io/blog/)

How can i set exactly this theme to my github? Some help and guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to `main.css` file is broken on your site.

The reason is in your `blank.html` layout. It prepends site `baseUrl` from config: [/_layouts/blank.html#L11](https://github.com/ZeeshanShabbir/blog/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/blank.html#L11)

Change [`baseUrl` property](https://github.com/ZeeshanShabbir/blog/blob/gh-pages/_config.yml#L7) in your `config.yml` to `/blog`:

```
baseurl: "/blog"
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but i have changed the baseurl to /bog but layout is still broken